# SFDX force:data:tree:export Document "Reference"

Tags: salesforcedx, data-export, import

Since you cannot have a formal field relationship (Lookup) from an SObject to a Document object we have a SObject (let's call it "Settings") that "references" a Document object by simply storing a Document's Id in a text property.

Since doing a data tree export can't possibly do the right thing here for our Settings object, how are people dealing with this when they want to export such data from one org and import into another?

I can't see a way to do this without first having to import the document to the new org.  Then get the new document id. And finally,  replace old Document id with the new one in the export file that was generated for our Settings table before importing the Settings into the new org.

Seems like a lot of hokey-pokey.  I feel like this must be a solved problem that I'm missing the answer to.